# Why does running as Junit Test lead to deterioration of performance?

Tags: java, junit

I run a function and measure the total time it takes. First this was written as a Junit test and the same written as a class with a main function. Calling the main executes the same function as run by Junit.

```
Via TestRunner:
Total time taken for transformation rules: 49

Via JUnit:
Total time taken for transformation rules: 515
```

The time is measured in ms. The JUnit test takes 10x more time than running it from main function. Does JUnit do something extra which I am missing here? Why has the performance deteriorated so much?

Comment: "does junit do something extra" - yes of course, but that doesn't lead to performance issues. How are you running the test and how are you running the application?

Comment: how are you measuring performance? doing microbenchmarks can be tricky due to JIT optimizations. And have you tried using a profiler to see where the time is being spent?

Comment: A single datapoint says nothing. It's likely not x10 in general, but a constant overhead plus a much lower factor. Also heavily depends on how granular the tests are, which report(s) are being generated, etc.